# PHP require_once including file but variables not being used on new httpd/php/mysql CentOS install

Tags: php, centos, apache

Ok, so I have a file called include.conf like so:

```
<?
$var1 = 1;
?>
```

and then I have index.php like so:

```
<?php
require_once('include.conf');
print($var1);
?>
```

and on my MAMP install on OSX it works fine. I transfered it across to my new server running CentOS HTTPD/PHP/MySQL and it no longer works. I know the file gets included because I can see it in the loaded source but it doesn't pick up the variables. It just returns:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: var1 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 3
```

I'd appreciate any help/advice.

P.S. this isn't my actual code, its incredibly simplified but I have tested it like this and it still fails.

Comment: short_tags support enabled on your server? try <?PHP in include.conf

Comment: Changed them, same problem.

Comment: Fixed it, when I changed the tags I put the ? at the end of php (Stupid mistake). But yeah, it would appear short tags aren't enabled. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps short tags aren't enabled on your new server?